# Adblock блокирует полезный контент

Tags: joomla, html

Пилю потихоньку сайт на joomla 3, в [одном месте](http://artcenter-hm.ru/index.php/svedeniya-ob-obrazovatelnoj-organizatsii/materialno-tekhnicheskoe-obespechenie-i-osnashchennost-obrazovatelnogo-protsessa) потребовалось вставить документ, использовал плагин для отображения документов (использует движок от google). И, внезапно, выяснилось, что адблок его блокирует. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как вариант, можно изменить классы и айдишники во вьюхе плагина.

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Алексей Скляр А где это можно менять? Не похоже, что это доступно в настройках плагина
https://yadi.sk/i/CHt7u8A7cv4RJ

Comment: У div имя класса `adv-container`, а внутри iframe. Я тоже бы банил:)

Меняйте имя класса div'а для начала.

Comment: @KoVadim да, но где это можно менять? Из административной панели я не нашел, как это сделать (скриншот выше).

Comment: Из панели можно добавить в графе CSS class, но он по факту меняется с "adv-container" на "adv-container gdocs". Если вручную (при нажатии f12) переименовать на "gdocs", то адблок перестает блокировать, но как сделать так, чтобы с таким именем класса и формировалась страница?

Comment: там есть есть Document viewer engine. Может им поиграть.

Answer (score 0):

Как другой вариант, проверяйте скриптом, остался ли в странице ваш `div`, и если его вырезали, показывайте сообщение типа

> На этом сайте есть отличные штуки, но ваш адблок их не пропустил. Выключите адблок на моём сайте: так вы получите документы, а я смогу немного заработать на рекламе, чтобы поддерживать этот сайт.

Comment: А вот это плохая затея. Обычно такие окошки банятся сразу:)

Answer (score 0):

Adblock блокирует все элементы где в классе встречается

> ad

http://screencast.com/t/Dc5BoA4f3